# How to speed up exporting large Excel file using php and SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, excel, export-to-excel

I am trying to export Excel in php having more than 100k records but it took more than an hour to export the record set.

I am using SQL Server as my database.

Is there any way to speed up the entire process?

Comment: I'm not even sure Excel can handle 100k records. Why do you need to export the whole lot?

Comment: You might try exporting to CSV and use MSSQL to send it to a file, picking up the file when it's finished.

Comment: @Jared Farrish - Can you please provide me with the MSSQL Query to export the data as CSV.

Comment: Have you tried searching for that? There's already a few questions on that here on SO. Some of the links under Related to the right of these comments would probably work as well.

Comment: @JamWaffles -- Excel 2007 and up can handle over a million rows per sheet.

Comment: How are you writing to Excel? Is this a CSV file, or are you using one of the PHP Libraries that is capable of creating an Excel (BIFF, SPreadsheetML or OfficeOpenXML) file?

Answer (score 1):

**One option** would be to make sure you minimize disk IO which means grouping multiple writes to the file into one batch. Such as writing 100 records at once not just 1.

This is easily possible if you're writing CSV files but I'm not sure if the PHP Excell library you're using exposes this implementation detail.

**One other option** would be saving your file in a RamDisk Drive, a small filesystem allocated in  ram and mapped as a disk drive.

On Unix/Linux platforms /dev/shm is a shared memory filesystem. Reading/Writing stuff from it is much much faster than HDD disk IO.

If you're using Windows i remember there were some RamDisk solutions. You'd have to download some 3rd party software that implements a windows disk driver.